# Django Auto add id field in database i don't want it

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-model-field

Django auto add id field in database 
i don't want to add id field in my database please help

```
 fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer to designate another model field as the primary key, add `primary_key=True` to the desired field. See related [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#s-automatic-primary-key-fields). E.g.

```
username = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
```

If you don't need a primary key *at all*, maybe a relational table is not the best place to save your data. Django needs a primary key in its tables and doesn't provide a way to prevent its creation.